# how to Limit the no of displaying rows in DataTables node.js #express #mysql

Tags: node.js, datatables

## want to use Server-side processing

I have searched and got some details from https://github.com/jpravetz/node-datatable am able to get the result of the query from database but not able to set a limit to no of rows.

Comment: Server side processing usually relies on you limiting the result set length in the backend, and sending the requested length as @Aminadav suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `start` and `length` properties in the `buildQuery` functions.

I analytze the source code for that (That why I like open-source projects):

https://github.com/jpravetz/node-datatable/blob/master/lib/builder.js#L212

Comment: Welcome to SO. If it helps you, you can accept the answer. (Press the `v`)

Comment: yes I will surely do that but right now just little bit short of reputation.